# regex pattern accepting comma and colon

Tags: java, regex

I am searching for regex pattern that matches the following String. I am using this regex pattern as,

```
^;[A-za-z0-9,:]+
```

Above regex doesn't matches the following.
I am looking for all given string to be matched with regex pattern.

:a123,234,444:322 //String started with semicolon and values are separated with comma and colon
;123,A234:123;123,345,456:999,456 // Above case with repeated condition

;;123,345,C555:123 //String started with double semicolon

Can anyone provide regex pattern that matches above string.

Comment: Your strings have colons `:`, while your regex has only semicolons `;`. What kind of match are you expecting?

Comment: Your strings contain colons (:) and your regex doesn't.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Could you please rewrite your question so that it is more understandable what you want and what you don't want. Should all three been matched?

Comment: ":a123,234,444:322 //String started with semicolon". It actually starts with a colon. Is this a typo ?

Comment: Please be accurate, what do you want to match, the inner values separated or the complete string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one

```
[;:]+[A-za-z0-9,;:]+
```

will work for all three you want, [see online on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/RLyFWA/1/).

1. `[;:]+`: Started with one or more `;` or `:` .
2. `[A-za-z0-9,;:]+`: You miss' a `:` here.

Answer (score 0):

You can match the above with this regex

```
^;+[A-za-z0-9,;:]+
```

Modifications:

1. `;+` will match 1 or more semicolons
2. colon `:` has been added in characters you want to match

Comment: For first case OP says it starts with a semicolon but in the string there is a colon. I assume it is a typo and string should start with semicolon.